# AttributeError: __exit__ while processing all files in directory

Tags: python, io, file-handling

I'm essentially trying to process every single file in the current working directory with a python script. Despite my best efforts I keep getting this error when I run my code:

```
File "script.py", line 9, in <module>
    with my_file as f:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Here is my code:

```
import os

for my_file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    first = True;
    movie_id = 0;

    with my_file as f:
        for line in f:
            if first == False:
                sys.stdout.write(movie_id + "," + line);
            else:
                movie_id = line
                movie_id = movie_id[0:len(movie_id) - 2]
                first = False
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You probably intended to call `open()` on `my_file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two redundant `close()`'s,  the `with:` suite takes care of it.  Just:

```
import os

for my_file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print file
    first = True;
    movie_id = 0;

    with open(my_file) as f:
    #    ^^^^^       ^
        for line in f:
            if first == False:
                sys.stdout.write(movie_id + "," + line);
            else:
                movie_id = line
                movie_id = movie_id[0:len(movie_id) - 2]
                first = False
```

Folliwing OP edit:

the error is telling you that `f` has no `__exit__` method, and thus cannot be used as a Context Manager.  That's because, as Steve Jessop comments, you forgot `open()`

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, however, with or without the closes I still get the same error, i'll update my code with the changes though